# Как настроить репозиторий в bintray, чтобы ссылаться на него без прямого пути в gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, library

Загружал свои библиотеки на bintray, всегда работало так.

1) Загружаем пеккейдж на bintray

2) Добавляем в build.gradle файл прямой путь к репозиторию

```
maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/{user}/{repo}' }
```

3) добавляем депенденси в gradle

4) в настройках пеккейджа на bintray нажимаем на add to jcenter, описываем проект

5) дожидаемся аппрува, убираем из списка репозиториев в build.gradle путь из пункта (2)

Год-два я не добавлял новые пеккейджи на bintray. И вот теперь, добавил и словил после аппрува проблему - я убираю прямой путь к репозиторию из списка репозиториев в gradle, оставляю там jcenter()

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
//        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/{user}/{repo}' }
    }
}
```

но gradle не может найти мои пеккейджи. Кто то работает с bintray? Кто знает как можно обойти прямое добавление пути в список репозиториев?

Comment: А тут появились библиотеки? http://jcenter.bintray.com/

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja нет, но я не нахожу там и старых, на которые ссылаюсь без прямого пути. Здесь появились - https://bintray.com/beta/#/bintray/jcenter